# jquery-ui-tabs. passing a querystring

Tags: jquery, user-interface, query-string

How could I  pass a query string (?id=avalue) with each of the below links associated to the below tabs. I am attempting to open external content within the tabs (that it's working fine) but I have failed to pass a parameter with the urls. The value for the parameter would be the same for each link.

My functioning code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({spinner:'<b>Retrieving Data...</b>'}); 

        });

 </script>


<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
           <li><a href="table.aspx"><span>Introduction</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="RequestActionUpdate.aspx"><span>Update</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="tabstesttarget.aspx"><span>Target</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="table.aspx" ><span>View History</span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Any help you can offer me will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`ajaxOptions`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-ajaxOptions) option. The tabs widget will pass these options onto [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax).

The following code uses the `data` option of the `jQuery.ajax()` function to pass the result of the `getId` function  (a Unix-style time code in this example) to the server when a tab is selected.
The request url will look something like `RequestActionUpdate.aspx?id=1255015611701`:

```
function getId() {
  return (new Date()).getTime();
}

$("#tabs").tabs({
  spinner:'<b>Retrieving Data...</b>',
  ajaxOptions: { data: { id: getId } }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. This was the solution I had attempted to find, but couldn't see how to do it. Definitely an elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: This doesn't change the value with every new tab select, it only grabs the getId value once.

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode the parameter to each link:

```
<li><a href="RequestActionUpdate.aspx?id=avalue"><span>Update</span></a></li>
```

This should work just fine. What exactly is not working for you? Or you have something else in mind?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the parameter would be the same for  each tab but will vary for each session. I am intending to take it from, probably, a hidden box.

Answer (score 1):

From the searching that I've done, the best way to approach this without having to do something ugly like:

```
window.location = href + '?id=avalue'
```

would be to update the anchor hrefs on the page load. Grab whatever ID/value you need, and just append it;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    value = "?id=foobar"
    $("#tabs ul li a").attr('href', ($(this).attr('href') + value) );
});
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add an event observer on all the links?

```
$("#tabs ul li a").click(
    function(){
       $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + $('#someHiddenInput').val());
     }
);
```